# Compatibility problem between maven and maven-resources-plugin

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin

I'm using maven-resources-plugin to copy a file from resources dir to output dir and inject a variable;
there is the pom of the project:

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <configuration>
                <resources>
                    <resource>
                        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                        <includes>
                            <include>**/*.properties</include>
                        </includes>
                        <filtering>true</filtering>
                    </resource>
                </resources>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

the resource file is something like this:

```
operation=${var}
```

and in he pom there is:

```
<properties>
    <operation>true</operation>
</properties>
```

When I build the project (mvn -U clean package ) locally everything works fine: the file .properties is correctly inside the jar and it contains "operation=true".
The problem appears when I deploy the jar to my artifactory. If I download and open the jar from artifactory I can still find the .properties file, but in this case it contains: "operation=${var}" (the plugin doesn't inject the value of the variable). The command for the build inside the .yml file is the same that I run locally (mvn -U clena package). 
 Any suggestions? 
The only difference that I can see is that on my computer I have maven 3.6.1 and on the server where I build the project for artifactory there is maven 3.3.3.

Comment: A lot has been changed between `v3.3.3` and `v3.6.1`. The [`v3.3.9`](http://maven.apache.org/docs/3.3.9/release-notes.html) has some fixes for for `maven-resource-plugin`. I suggest, try upgrading the maven version to confirm the issue.

Comment: @fabfas thank you, but I can't update the maven version on the server ( it's a server of a client ); the only chenges that I can make are on the java program (for example change the version of the plugin).